# ES6 async/await parallel processing

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am writing code for async/await parallel processing but it's not processing all the records if any error occurred not processing rest of the record

```
async function test() {

 let i = 0
 let userId = [5000, 1000, 7000]
 try {
    while (i < userId.length) {
        const userEmail = await getUserEmail(userId[i])
        let sendEmailResult = await postSendUserEmail(userEmail)
        i++
    }
 } catch (err) {
    console.log('Got error')
 }
}


(async () => {
 await test();
 // Do some logic here 
 console.log('All  done')
})().catch(e => console.log(e));



function getUserEmail(milis) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (milis == 1000) {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Rejecting millis', milis)
            return reject('Got error')
        }, milis);

    } else {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Processing millis', milis)
            return resolve(milis);
        }, milis);

    }
  })
}


function postSendUserEmail(milis) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (milis == 1000) {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Rejecting  email', milis)
            return reject('Got email error')
        }, milis);

    } else {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Sending  email', milis)
            return resolve(milis);
        }, milis);

    }
})
}
```

Here getUserEmail is rejecting promise when value is 1000,

My question is while loop processing all the operation in parallel for each records and why all records are not processing if any reject occurs then how to process all the records whether resolve/reject using async/await

Answer (score 0):

The `await`s you have inside the `while` loop is blocking the execution and continuation of the loop until they've completed.

You could move those function calls to a separate function and it will continue to execute:

```
async function test() {

    let i = 0
    let userId = [5000, 1000, 7000]
    try {
        while (i < userId.length) {
            handleUser(userId[i]);
            // const userEmail = await getUserEmail(userId[i])
            // let sendEmailResult = await postSendUserEmail(userEmail)
            i++
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Got error')
    }
}

async function handleUser(user) {
    const userEmail = await getUserEmail(user)
    let sendEmailResult = await postSendUserEmail(userEmail)
}
```

Or, if you want each user to be handled 1 at a time, you can move the `try...catch` to be inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try/catch` block is outside of the loop. If you rearrange it so that it is on a per-iteration basis you can avoid the situation where one bad apple ruins the bunch. Try changing your test function to:

```
    while (i < userId.length) {
      try {
        const userEmail = await getUserEmail(userId[i])
        let sendEmailResult = await postSendUserEmail(userEmail)
      } catch (err) {
        // err handling here
        // ....
     }
      // Need to do this regardless of whether or not error occured.
      i++
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid rejecting in your async methods and returns result data instead of it.
So `getUserEmail` and `postSendUserEmail` may looks like:

```js
function getUserEmail(milis) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (milis == 1000) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Rejecting millis', milis)
            return reject({ success: false, data: 'Got error' })
        }, milis);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Processing millis', milis)
            return resolve({ success: true, data: milis });
        }, milis);
    }
  })
}

function postSendUserEmail(milis) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (milis == 1000) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Rejecting  email', milis)
            return reject({ success: false, data: 'Got error' })
        }, milis);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Sending  email', milis)
            return resolve({ success: true, data: milis });
        }, milis);
    }
})
```

As you see, now both methods resolves `{ success: boolean, data: any }` object with `data` property as a method result when `success = true` and `data` as an error otherwise.
Also both methods now can't rejects, so your loop will process next iteration even if error happen. All you need is handle results like this:

```js
async function test() {
   let userId = [5000, 1000, 7000]
   try {
       for (const id of userId) {
           const userEmail = await getUserEmail(id)
           if (userEmail.success) {
               let sendEmailResult = await postSendUserEmail(userEmail.data)
           } else {
               console.log('Ooops, error happen but I still works!')
           }
       }
   } catch (err) {
       console.log('Got error')
   }
}
```